# Windows server in different timezone than it's domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

My question is, can we run a windows server in a different time zone than it's domain controller? All my searches came up with results for time syncronization, but that's not what I'm interested in.

Right now all our on-premises servers are in a domain and in CET time zone. Can anything go wrong if we set one of the servers to UTC?
The reason: all cloud servers are in UTC, and we use this server for testing. The domain controller and the rest of our servers will stay in the same time zone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the server will sync with the time of the DC but will adopt the correct timezone.

Timezone are stored inside the registry, and dont sync with the computer/server sync.

The DC use NTP and use UTC, the timezone is used for the display/log.

ie; Current system time + Time zone = Display time

In example I have customer with employee in other timezone, and when the employe come back at the main office, the sync work, but it just display the time as the timezone configured into the computer.

If you have problem with login, it's more a problem with time drifting, and both server are out of sync.